# How to implement this generic interface for this C# method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ICopyable
{
    void Copy<T>(T source) where T : class;
}
```

I've tried to implement it, but I keep getting this error:

> The constraints for type parameter 'TListing' of method 'Foo.Core.Models.AggregateRoot.Copy(TListing)' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'FooCore.Interfaces.ICopyable.Copy(T)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.

```
public abstract class AggregateRoot : ICopyable
{
    public virtual void Copy<TListing>(TListing newAggregateRoot) 
        where TListing : AggregateRoot
    {
       // my code here.
    }
}
```

[image]

Why does it fail? My `AggregateRoot` is a class.

Comment: did you try to define T : class at the definition of the interface instead?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. sorry.

Comment: this was explained in the answer below :)

Comment: Do you really need to specify the `where TListing : AggregateRoot`? If `TListing` is a class (and not an interface, an enum or a struct that is) it should work as is...

Comment: @TimBourguignon what would the method look like then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say your code compiled. You could then do this:

```
class Derived : AggregateRoot
{
}
```

And then:

```
var derived = new Derived();
ICopyable copyable = derived;
copyable.Copy<string>("Hello!");
```

This would be fine, because `ICopyable.Copy<T>` requires a type argument that's a class - and `string` is a class. But it would have to be dispatched to a method that actually expects a `T : AggregateRoot`. This would have to fail at runtime - so the compiler simply rejects it beforehand.

In more general terms, the problem is that you are trying to implement a specific interface with an implementation that is more strict than what the interface says. This is not type safe - and it would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) with respect to contravariance of inputs.

But even if it *was* type safe and it didn't violate the LSP, it would still be rejected by the compiler. C# requires that specializing a class and implementing an interface is always done with exact, invariant signatures and identical  constraints. This is spelled out in the [C# specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), in *13.4.3 Implementation of generic methods*:

> When a generic method implicitly implements an interface method, the constraints given for each method type parameter must be equivalent in both declarations [...]

But still, C# allows variance in implicit conversions between generic interfaces (of the same generic type definition). Thus, your code would work if it was changed to something like this:

```
public interface ICopyable<in T>
    where T : class
{
    void Copy(T source);
}

public abstract class AggregateRoot : ICopyable<AggregateRoot>
{
    public virtual void Copy(AggregateRoot newAggregateRoot) 
    {
       // my code here.
    }
}
```

And now you can do the following, which compiles and is type safe:

```
var derived = new Derived();
ICopyable<AggregateRoot> aggregateCopyable = derived;
ICopyable<Derived> derivedCopyable = aggregateCopyable;
derivedCopyable.Copy(derived);
```

Comment: Hmm.. so I have to define it at the class level? why is that?

Comment: @Pure.Krome I just realized that my initial paragraph was misleading on its own. See my edit.